# http.get and http.request are both being extremely slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When trying to load simple JSON APIs with the following code, I noticed the speeds were extremely slow:

```
function get(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(r) {
        var body = "";
        r.on('data', function(d) {
            body+=d;
        });
        r.on('end', function() {
            callback(body, false)
        });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        callback(null, err.message.code)
    });
}
```

Or posting with the following code:

```
function post(url, post_data, callback) {
if (!post_data) post_data = "";
var Proto = url.split("://")[0]+":";
var Host = url.split("://")[1].split("/")[0];
var Path = "/"+url.split("://")[1].replace("/", "#CHECK").split("#CHECK")[1];
var req = http.request({
    host: Host,
    port: '80',
    path: Path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
}, function(r) {
    var body = '';
    r.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
    });
    r.on('end', function() {
        callback(body);
    });     
}).on('error', function (err) {
    callback(null, err.message.code)
});
req.write(querystring.stringify(post_data));
req.end();
}
```

Both take an extremely long time to go through, usually averaging me about 150-300 milliseconds per request on small files that would take me under 80ms to load in Google Chrome. To test, I used Google Chrome to benchmark and sent simple get and post requests, but it took 2 to 3 times longer to receive a response in node for each request than it did in Google Chrome. After doing some research, I found out it could possibly be due to Chrome, like most browsers, using the `Connection:"keep-alive"` header, but adding this in the headers seemed to have no impact. I'm already setting `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100000;` so I know that isn't the issue. How I can speed up my requests?

Still have yet to find anything, if anyone knows if anything to speed things up please post a reply

Comment: Try `var body = Buffer.alloc(0); r.on('data', function(d) { body = body.concat([d]); }); r.on('end', function() { callback(body.toString()); });` instead of doing implicit conversion from buffers to UTF-8 strings. I'm not sure if this will actually improve speed, which is why I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I meant `body = Buffer.concat([body, d]);` Either way, I just tried out my method, it seems to be consistently slower than implicit string concatenation. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: first check the time with curl - it is more relevant. `time curl URL`

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov does doing something like `var x = (new Date()).getTime(); get(url, function() { console.log(x-(new Date()).getTime()+"ms") }` not work as reliably? I used it for both the chrome benchmarking and the node benchmarking so I doubt it would have much of an effect, definitely not enough to triple the request times

Comment: chrome is a blackbox, it may use some kind of prefetch or cache. With CURL you'll be sure about real server response time

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov it were cached it wouldn't be taking 80ms to load, more like 2-5ms, and I append the current timestamp to the url to avoid caching anyway